# Texture Only Correct in Texture Paint Solid Mode

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I am working with UV maps and texturing in Blender 2.91. I've unwrapped the UV, exported, colored the UV map, and made sure the texture lines up with the UV map in Blender (it does). While in Texture Paint solid mode, the texture maps to the mesh correctly. However, in Texture Paint render/material preview modes, UV Editing mode, and Layout mode, the texture doesn't line up with the mesh. Under Shading, I've also made sure to use Texture Coordinate (UV). Any help would be appreciated.

Project:
[image]

EDIT: added .blend file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple UV maps, and you painted on another one while rendering (***UVMap.003*** <=> ***UVMap***). Go to the UV maps, and set ***UVMap.003*** active for rendering by clicking the **camera icon**. There you can also clean up and delete the unused UV maps. You can see the layout in *UV Editing* workspace.

(Multiple UV maps are useful when you want to change the texture layout. You can bake or transfer parts of the texture with the clone brush from one image to another.)

[image: switch UV maps]
<sup>Switch UV maps (Material Preview mode)</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much. I saw all those maps in UV Editing tab but wasn't sure if they were relevant or if I could delete them.